# Exception while Lazy Loading with closed EntityManager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, lazy-loading

I know EclipseLink allows to access Lazy Collections outside of a transaction.

My Lazy Collection is accessed in a background Task which frequently gets cancelled.

When the `Task` gets cancelled, I get the following Exception:

> [EL Info]: query: 2017-11-01
>   13:59:01.245--UnitOfWork(39449946)--Communication failure detected
>   when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction.
>   Attempting to retry query. Error was: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection
>   closed by unknown interrupt.

I would like to know

1) is there is a way to disable EclipseLink's feature to Lazy-load outside the transaction? (for debugging reasons)?

2) How to catch this exception?

3) How to prevent this exception?

The Application is Desktop JavaFX, with EclipseLink JPA.

Comment: I'm not sure which feature you are looking to disable. IF the relationship is lazy and you are going to access it later, you will need to fetch it before closing the transaction performing the initial read and closing the EntityManager.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ive updated the question.

Comment: 1: no.  2: its a warning not an exception. You can only catch it if it is passed up to the application, and presumably you would notice that in your task or app logging.  3: don't kill the transaction while the task is still processing, putting hooks into the task to stop instead. The message itself is tied to query retry behaviour which can be customized, https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/370441/

Comment: What is your runtime environment? Is this background thread spawned by some EJB?